# How to animate a heatmap in Plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly, heatmap

The [Plotly documentation on heatmap animation](https://plot.ly/python/heatmap-animation/) is pretty difficult to understand. Could someone explain how to animate a heatmap?

---

Here is my specific example.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def plane_wave(phase):
    return np.sin(8*np.pi * (xx - phase))

zz = plane_wave(0)

trace = go.Heatmap(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=zz,
)
# This doesn't work:
frames = [
    {'data': [{'z': plane_wave(phase)}]} for phase in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
]

data=[trace]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, frames=frames)
iplot(fig)
```

I get

> `PlotlyDictKeyError: 'z' is not allowed in 'scatter'`
> `Path To Error: ['frames'][0]['data'][0]['z']`

Here's a picture of the heatmap I'm trying to animate:

[image: Plane wave heatmap]

Comment: there is some SO markup in your code where you define `frames`.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem with what I'd done - I needed to specify `'type': 'heatmap'`

```
frames = [
    {
        'data': [{
            'z': plane_wave(angle, phase),
            'type': 'heatmap'
        }]
    } for phase in np.linspace(0, 0.1, 30)
]
```

However, the jupyter notebook now gives this error

> `IOPub data rate exceeded. The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it. To change this limit, set the config variable
>   --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit.`

I followed the instructions [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/tips-for-using-plotly-with-jupyter-notebook-5-0-the-latest-version/4156) to stop this error. However, this is highly inconvenient. Also, the step between each frame takes is a noticeable gap (i.e., the frame rate is low). I wonder if there is a better method for animating a heatmap