# Plotlty: How to change transition time in animated heatmap?

Tags: python, animation, plotly, heatmap

I'm building an animated heatmap in python with plotly (just like what's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333615/how-to-create-a-heatmap-animation-with-plotly-express)).

I'd just like to make the transition quicker (I have a thousand step).

Here's the code from @rpanai I'd like to adapt

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

N = 50
M = np.random.random((N, 10, 10))

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Heatmap(z=M[0])],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Frame 0",
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None])])]
    ),
    frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Heatmap(z=M[i])],
                     layout=go.Layout(title_text=f"Frame {i}")) 
            for i in range(1, N)]
)

fig.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
args=[None])])]
```

with:

```
args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 1000, "redraw": True},}])])]
```

And change `1000` (that's millisenconds) to a duration that suits your needs.

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

N = 50
M = np.random.random((N, 10, 10))

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Heatmap(z=M[0])],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Frame 0",
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 2000, "redraw": True},}])])]
    ),
    frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Heatmap(z=M[i])],
                     layout=go.Layout(title_text=f"Frame {i}")) 
            for i in range(1, N)]
)

fig.show()
```